# read a polynomial from input stream in lisp

Tags: sorting, input, lisp

Reads a polynomial from a list pl (see below for input format) and returns it as a sorted list.

Example: `(ReadPolynomial2 '(99 0 17 200 3 150 8 200 0 0))` should return `((99 0) (3 150) (25 200))`

Comment: wow, you didn't even copy all of the exam

Comment: I need to do this ASAP..I have no knowledge of Lisp and I was down with fever last week so was not able to work on it

Comment: This is not an exam. The numbers(coefficients) with the same degree should be added and then displayed.

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need it, but here it is a possible solution:

```
(defun ReadPolynomial2 (lst)
  (let ((even-positions (loop for p in (cdr lst) by #'cddr collect p)))
    (loop for p in (remove-duplicates even-positions)
          collect (list (loop for x on lst by #'cddr
                              when (= p (second x))
                              sum (first x)) p))))
```